# Updating the value of a variable from the outer scope within an if block

Tags: java, if-statement, scope

```
int i = 3;
int j = 2;
int k = 1;

Printer printer = new Printer();

if (printer.getTotalAmount() > 0) {
   if (printer.getType().equals("canon")) {
      if (i >= j) {
         i = i-j;  // i=3-2, so i will be 1 now
      }
   }
   if (printer.getType().equals("epson")) {
      if (i >= k) {
        i = i - k; // it should be i = 1-1 and i will be 0 now
      }
   }
}
```

My problem is that the variable `i`'s value is not updated after the previous `if` statement. Due to block scope, the variable `i`'s value is still 3.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is not clear. if the `if` condition doesnt match then control will not go inside if block. So it will not do `i=i-j` operation.
And if-else is not a loop. its a conditional block

Comment: May be problem inside if-condition? Please post them.

Comment: your code is fine, scoping is OK -- the variable belongs to the scope where it is declared, so updating it inside the `if` is OK and should be visible. The problem is somewhere else. Post the entire snipped that doesn't work.

Comment: Most important thing here is the condition you're evaluating. So if you could share the actual code that is not working, helping you would be easier.

Comment: I edited my question. Please take a look

Comment: Please print `printer.getTotalAmount()` and `printer.getType()` after `Printer printer = new Printer();` line. and post the code of `Printer` class

Answer (score 0):

Your two `if` statements represent mutually-exclusive conditions. The printer's type can be "canon" OR it can be "epson". Never both. So only one of your two `if` conditions will be met, and only one of the two code blocks will be executed.

Say, for example, that your Printer's type is "epson". When the first condition is evaluated, it will check whether "epson" is equal to "canon". Since they are *not* equal, the condition evaluates to `false` and all of the code inside of your `if () {/* code */}` block is completely skipped.

Your theory behind the scope causing the issue isn't accurate: since the variable is declared outside of the `if` block, the updated value will be reflected in every location that has access to that variable.

You need to update your logic to account for the fact that only one of the scenarios will occur or, if this is just a code simplification, find a more appropriate scenario analogous to your real code.

It may be helpful to review Oracle's [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) on the `if` statement if this still isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add debug statements to know more about flow of your program
becuase you didn't mention the value of `printer.getTotalAmount()` and `printer.getType()`
on which value of `i` is depend.
e.g.

```
System.out.println("Total Amount:"+ printer.getTotalAmount());
if (printer.getTotalAmount() > 0) {
   System.out.println("Type:"+ printer.getType());
   if (printer.getType().equals("canon")) {
      System.out.println("inside if canon");
      if (i >= j) {
         i = i-j;  // i=3-2, so i will be 1 now
      }
   }
   if (printer.getType().equals("epson")) {
      System.out.println("inside if epson");
      if (i >= k) {
        i = i - k; // it should be i = 1-1 and i will be 0 now
      }
   }
}
```